# multiple words act as single word in search - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue with tags such as `social media`, `two words`, `tag with many spaces` have a multiplied score for each word in search query.

How can I achieve to search `two words` as one word instead getting different score when searching `two` and `two words`

**Here is a visual representation the current results score:**

```
+-----------------------+-------+
| search                | score |
+-----------------------+-------+
| two                   | 2.76  |
| two words             | 5.53  |
| tag with many spaces  | 11.05 |
| singleword            | 2.76  |
```

**Here is a visual representation of what I want:**

```
+-----------------------+-------+
| search                | score |
+-----------------------+-------+
| two                   | 2.76  |
| two words             | 2.76  |
| tag with many spaces  | 2.76  |
| singleword            | 2.76  |
```

There are multiple tags in each document. each tag search is broken down by a comma `,` in PHP and outputted like the query below

Assuming a document has multiple tags including `two words` and `singleword`, this would be the search query:

```
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "tags.name": "two words"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "tags.name": "singleword"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "functions": [
            {
                "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "tags.votes"
                }
            }
        ],
        "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
}
```

The score will be different if searching `two` instead of `two words`

**Here is how the result looks like when searching `two words`**

```
{
    "_index": "index",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "u10q42cCZsbFNf1W0Tdq",
    "_score": 4.708793,
    "_source": {
        "url": "example.com",
        "title": "title of the document",
        "description": "some description of the document",
        "popularity": 9,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "two words",
                "votes": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "singleword",
                "votes": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "othertag",
                "votes": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "random",
                "votes": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Here is the result when searching `two` instead of `two words`**

```
{
    "_index": "index",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "u10q42cCZsbFNf1W0Tdq",
    "_score": 3.4481666,
    "_source": {
        "url": "example.com",
        "title": "title of the document",
        "description": "some description of the document",
        "popularity": 9,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "two words",
                "votes": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "singleword",
                "votes": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "othertag",
                "votes": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "random",
                "votes": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Here is the mapping (for the tags specifically)**

```
"tags": {
  "type": "nested",
  "include_in_parent": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "votes": {
      "type": "long"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried searching with `"\"two words\""` and `"*two words*"` but it gave no difference.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Do you really require scoring?

Comment: @NishantSaini Yes. The score needs to be boosted with tags.votes. if the tags.name is found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the non analyzed string for your matching and switch to a term query.

Can you try :

```
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "tags.name.keyword": "two words"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "tags.name.keyword": "singleword"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "functions": [
            {
                "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "tags.votes"
                }
            }
        ],
        "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
}
```

With your actual implementation, when you do a `match` query with the query "two words" it will analyze your query to search for token "two" and "words" in your tags. So documents with tag "two words" will match the two tokens and will be boosted.

Comment: This worked exactly as I wanted! I have never heard of the `.keyword` use for the fields before. Also, is it possible to change the `should` to `must` ? When I do this, I get no results unless I only search a single tag. It would be great to get results that MUST include the tags

Comment: Ahh. I just found out. It's because I use a `nested` search. Solve this by put the must/must_not outside of the `nested` field. Thank you for your help!